# using xsl:param variable in xs:schema element output

Tags: xslt, xsd

I am trying to output the following line from an XSLT script. It is the first line just after `xsl:template match="/"`. What I am trying to do is to transform XML document into an XML schema and need to output the `xs:schema` tag in particular way.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:ed="http://test1"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" targetNamespace="{$ns_name}" xmlns:tns="{$ns_name}" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xsi:schemaLocation="http://test1 file://XmlSchemaAppinfo.xsd">
```

the `$ns_name` is a `xsl:param name="ns_name"`. It is resolved in the `targetNamespace="{$ns_name}"` correctly but in the `xmlns:tns="{$ns_name}"` it is output literally

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="akolodk" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xsi:schemaLocation="http://test1 file://XmlSchemaAppinfo.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ed="test1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="{$ns_name}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespace declarations are not treated the same as attributes, even though they look the same. The `xmlns:tns` will have been processed by the XML parser when the stylesheet was parsed, before it gets to the XSLT processor.

If you have XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<xsl:namespace name="tns" select="$ns_name"/>
```

to create a namespace node in the result tree but there's no easy way I know of to generate a dynamic namespace in XSLT 1.0. You can't use [`xsl:attribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes), the spec explicitly states that while

```
<xsl:attribute name="xmlns:xsl" namespace="whatever">http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform</xsl:attribute>
```

is not an error, it will generate an attribute, not a namespace declaration - the processor is required to ignore the `xmlns` prefix specified in the `name` and must use a different prefix to output the attribute.

If your processor supports the exslt `node-set` extension function then the following *might* work:

```
<xsd:schema .....>
  <xsl:variable name="tnsElement">
    <xsl:element name="tns:dummy" namespace="{$ns_name}"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($tnsElement)/*/namespace::tns"/>
```

but again the processor is allowed to ignore the prefix of the `xsl:element` `name` attribute and use a different prefix bound to the same URI, you'll have to test it with your processor.

(and you'll have to add `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"` to your `xsl:stylesheet` element).

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it didn't work for me... `Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element after an attribute node has already been added.`

Comment: @akolodk in that case try using just an `<xsd:schema>` literal element with no attributes (just namespaces), then my trick for the tns namespace, then use `xsl:attribute` to create the attributes.

Comment: hi, @Ian it worked!!! thanks!!! I had tweak some bits and pieces. Basically I decomposed the literal `<xs:schema>` element into `<xsl:element name="xs:schema" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`

Answer (score 0):

In XSL only some attributes can be written using [attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) (using the '{}' notation). In particular, xmlns attributes do not support the notation.

Comment: hi, thanks, however in the first reference it is stated that xmlns attributes are not interpreted as attribute value templates in the second reference says that if the attribute is xmlns it is also not going to be processed correctly: _XSLT processors may make use of the prefix of the QName specified in the name attribute when selecting the prefix used for outputting the created attribute as XML; however, they are not required to do so and, if the prefix is xmlns, they must not do so._

Comment: Correct. Removed the reference and see that Ian Roberts has provided a solution.